# 12.04 Unity - Windows Consistently Jump Behind Main Menu Bar

Tags: 12.04, unity, windows, interface

I have run a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and installed all the latest updates, and have not made any alterations to the interface. However I am presented with a persistent problem:

When using multiple applications or windows, when returning to a previously used application by clicking on the left side icon, I often find that entire folders/browser windows, have been moved above the unity bar, sometimes past the point of retrieval. I understand that in most circumstances pressing alt will drag the window back into place. However, after a few minutes when I return to the application, I find that invariably the window has been moved back off screen.

This time wasting error may seem innocuous, but multiply it by several command lines, browser windows, editors and the like, the task of ferrying logic between windows becomes much more arduous when one has to hunt and physically retrieve the proper screen from it's hiding place.

Is there a mechanism that I have overlooked that may be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Try this `unity --reset`